# Гугл-карты в оффлайн

Tags: android, google-maps

Задача создать Андроид приложение с картами Гугл. Как сделать, чтобы карты работали полностью в оффлайн-режиме?

Comment: много раз видел аналогичный вопрос, поищите лучше, есть ряд путей для решения.

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать следующую библиотеку https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid